# Regex to escape data to be displayed inside of `::before`

Tags: javascript, regex

Characters I need to escape: / \ " spaces ? $ # * + ? ( )  [ ] { } white space

using this right now: `props.text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\/^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&');`

But the above doesn't escape double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

`Characters I need to escape / \ " spaces ? $ # * + ? ( ) [ ] { } white space`

That would be this regex `/[\/\\"\s?$#*+?()\[\]{}]/`